# Using a Layout with a Canvas or specifying a background color with a background drawable on a canvas

Tags: android, layout, canvas, background

I'm creating a small game for a programming assignment. I'm trying to figure out how to set the background properly, but I can't seem to figure out.

I have a two linear layouts in my `main.xml`; one has a background color, and another layout that's inside it has a background image (transparent PNG). It shows up fine when I start up the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#aacceeff"
    >

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    >

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, I now have to add the animation. To do that I created a View object that loads up images and animates them. However, I now have to set the content view from the main activity to an instance of this new view object. When I do that, I get a null pointer exception because it cannot find the linear layout with id `background`:

```
BitmapDrawable tiledBackground = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background));
LinearLayout backgroundLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
tiledBackground.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
backgroundLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(tiledBackground); //backgroundLayout is null
```

I figure this is because the view is no longer the view that's specified in `main.xml`. If I remove this code, the code runs fine but I get a black background. I tried moving this specific snippet to the custom view and set the background to the image, but then I get the image with a black background; what I actually want is a transparent image with the background color showing through.

I guess what I'm trying to figure out is how to tell the custom view to use the layout I've defined in `main.xml`, or figure out a way to specify a background color *and* a background drawable for the custom view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using a color filter:

```
super(context);

BitmapDrawable tiledBackground = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background));
tiledBackground.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

//I determined the PorterDuff.Mode value mainly through trial and error
tiledBackground.setColorFilter(0xaacceeff, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);

this.setBackgroundDrawable(tiledBackground)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use findViewById method, you are looking for a layout or view from the layout.xml you specify in the setContentView method.

So if you call setContentView and set another xml file as the layout, then you will not be able to find a view from the previous layout.

In ideal cases setContentView is only called once for an activity. New activities are called for different screens. But you call also use the ViewFlipper class, you can add both your layouts as its childs. It will only show 1 child at a time. To show the next child you can use

```
viewflipper.setDisplayChild(1);
```

Comment: Right, I figured that part out. I'm trying to figure out how to get around that.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing how this will fix my issue. I'm basically trying to use the layout I've already defined, along with the custom view that I have. So I want the background in the main layout to show up with the custom view.